# Node.js get Json objects from mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I want my node.js program to return the objects that contain the correct value in an array of objects in mongodb.
And I want to get all objects that their Id is 2.
I tried some queries for example :

```
collection.find("Messages.Id":"2") 
collection.find("Id":"2")
```

But it doesnt return the right objects if it return anything.

My database in mongo looks like this:

```
    {"Messages" : 
    [ 
    {   "text":"aaa",
        "Id" : [ "1", "2" ] 
    }, 
    {   "texts" : "bbb",
        "Id" : [ "1", "3" ]
    },
]
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation. `("Messages.Id":"2")` is not valid JS syntax. It doesn't return anything because it doesn't run at all, due to the syntax error, which should have been displayed in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be a json object use `{}` in query

```
collection.find({"Messages.Id":"2"})
```

Comment: use **db.collection.find(......)**. check this link too  http://theholmesoffice.com/how-to-ge-data-from-mongodb-into-node-js/

Comment: `{"Messages.Id":"2"})` Did you actually test that? It will match a key `Messages.Id`, not an id within a hash in the array named Messages.